# D3 Date Parse Issue Return date: null

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js

I have data with Wed Oct 08 10:02:41 +0000 2014 as date. (source from Tweets)
By referring [mbstock/d3 - Time Formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting), here is my code:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y");
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
});  
console.log(data);
```

However, it seems not right, even trial and error with almost all possible ones. My result is:

```
date: "Wed Oct 08 10:02:41 +0000 2014"
dd: null
```

Not sure what's the issue, still, even read through all the related stackoverflow posts. Seems alike, but not solving mine. Helps needed. Thanks!

Comment: I can't replicate - this works for me (in the browser console on a page with d3.js included):
`var date = "Wed Oct 08 10:02:41 +0000 2014"; var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"); dateFormat.parse(date); // => Wed Oct 08 2014 11:02:41 GMT+0100 (BST)`

Comment: What browser version and locale?

Comment: joews: still not working here. explunit: How to check? Do they matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue!!

What I did, simply change the %Z into +0000, as below:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y");
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
});  
console.log(data);
```

[image]

Thanks for your helps :-)